# Crop sides of a numpy array by w elements (where w may be zero)

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I'd like to generalize the following to allow the number `w` of cropped elements to possibly be zero:

```
a = np.arange(42).reshape(6, 7)
w = 1  # Number of elements to crop on each side.
print(a[w:-w, w:-w])
```

And also in this generalization to arbitrary dimensions:

```
def crop(array, width):
  width = np.broadcast_to(width, array.ndim)
  return array[tuple(slice(w, -w) for w in width)]
```

The problem is that a `slice` with `stop=0` returns no elements.
What is the most elegant solution?  Is there any existing library function?

It would be wonderful if `numpy.pad` would allow negative values for cropping, but apparently it does not.

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary to write a custom function:

```
    def crop_array(array, width) -> np.ndarray:
      array = np.asarray(array)
      width = np.broadcast_to(width, array.ndim)
      assert np.all(width >= 0)
      return array[tuple((slice(None) if w == 0 else slice(w, -w)) for w in width)]
```